# Maintaining Rails environment through multiple deployment phases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, capistrano, loading, environment

I've been using Capistrano to deploy several rails apps to a single EC2 instance.  The apps are all served with Apache + Passenger.  The deployment phases form most of them is as follows:

-- fetch code, stage in a "releases/[timestamp]" subdirectory of the main app directory.

-- run bundler for staged release

-- run migrations for staged release

-- run asset compilation ("assets:precompile") rake task for staged release

-- restart the delayed_job task queue processing daemon and any other background processes

-- symlink the staged release to "current" (the passenger web root)

-- restart passenger (by touching "tmp/restart" in app directory)

This is a very standard Rails deployment procedure.  I've noticed that a huge bottleneck in it is loading of the rails environment for each task that requires it.  For one of my larger apps, environment loading takes ~40 seconds or more and that's repeated n times for the n tasks that require the rails environment (running bundler, migrations, asset compilation, delayed_job daemon).  Forgive if this is a naive question, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to load the environment only once for all of these tasks (preferably easier than consolidating the implementations of all of these tasks/jobs into a single rake task that loads the environment).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) for this.  It's a quick and easy way to deploy.  It utilizes [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) for customizing the vagrant box.  I think you'll want to create your own recipies (a chef thing..) to hit most of the items you've listed.  Once that's done ur good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ultimately concocted my own solution for this which works fine. Instead of running each of the commands that depend on the rails environment individually from the shell (using the Capistrano "run" method), I've bundled them together into a single rake task that depends on the rails environment. Where I previously ran "rake db:migrate", then "rake assets:precompile", etc., I now run a single rake task whose body includes "Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke" and "Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke". The environment now only gets loaded once.